# PrimeFaces component extension

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, taglib

i am creating my custom taglib by extending PrimeFaces components.

So far i have not got a problem i have successfully extended components but growl component does not work with my taglib.

```
import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;

import org.primefaces.component.growl.Growl;

@FacesComponent(value="MyGrowl")
public class MyGrowl extends Growl{


}
```

here is my extended class and taglib code

```
<tag>
        <tag-name>myGrowl</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>MyGrowl</component-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
```

What am i missing ? DataTable component works with same way but growl does not. Any clue would be helpful. Thank you.